# How do I generate a nested array that contains all possible 4 digit permutations 6 numbers with repeating values? ruby

Tags: ruby

Given a number of digits n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

I wanted to generate a nested array S that will contain all possible 4 digit permutations of n.
since 6^4 = 1296, there will be 1296 possible permutations.

Example:
S = [[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,2,2]...[6,6,6,6]]

I started the nested loop with the first index with value of [1,1,1,1]
Then used a for in loop with range 0..1295 and tried to carry over the value of S[i] to S[i+1]
then increment the value of S[i+1][x], where x always starts at 3 then is decremented until it reaches 0 then it becomes 3 again. The problem with my procedure is when i try to increment the S[i+1][x], S[i] also increments its S[i][x].
In the code below S is instead called 'all_possible_combinations'

```
all_possible_combinations = Array.new(1296) {Array.new(4)}
all_possible_combinations[0] = [1, 1 ,1 ,1]
x = 3
for i in 0..1295
    if i + 1 == 1296
        break
    else
        all_possible_combinations[i+1] = all_possible_combinations[i]
        all_possible_combinations[i+1][x] += 1
        x -= 1
        if x == 0
            x = 3
        end
    end
end
```

[Attached image shows debugging process where S[i][x] also gets incremented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P0Uv.png)

Comment: Note that you are referring to permutations, not combinations. For example, if `a = [1,2,3]` then `a.combination(2).to_a #=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]`, whereas `a.permutation(2).to_a #=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]]`.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? Are you talking about permutations or combinations? You consistently use the term "combination" no less than 9 times in your question, but from the code it looks like you are not asking about combinations at all, it looks like you want permutations. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may compute that array as follows.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

```
b = a.repeated_permutation(4).to_a
  #=> [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 1, 5],
  #    [1, 1, 1, 6], [1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 4],
  #    ...
  #    [6, 6, 5, 3], [6, 6, 5, 4], [6, 6, 5, 5], [6, 6, 5, 6], [6, 6, 6, 1],
  #    [6, 6, 6, 2], [6, 6, 6, 3], [6, 6, 6, 4], [6, 6, 6, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6]]
```

```
b.size
  #=> 1296
```

See [Array#repeated_permutation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation)

If the array `a` may contain duplicates and you wish to remove duplicate permutations you may wish to tack on [Array#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

```
a = [1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 6]
```

```
b = a.repeated_permutation(4).to_a.uniq
  #=> [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 6], [1, 1, 3, 1],
  #    [1, 1, 3, 3], [1, 1, 3, 6], [1, 1, 6, 1], [1, 1, 6, 3], 
  #    [1, 1, 6, 6], [1, 3, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1, 3], [1, 3, 1, 6],       
  #    [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 3, 3, 3], [1, 3, 3, 6], [1, 3, 6, 1],
  #    [1, 3, 6, 3], [1, 3, 6, 6], [1, 6, 1, 1], [1, 6, 1, 3],
  #    [1, 6, 1, 6], [1, 6, 3, 1], [1, 6, 3, 3], [1, 6, 3, 6],
  #    [1, 6, 6, 1], [1, 6, 6, 3], [1, 6, 6, 6], [3, 1, 1, 1],
  #    [3, 1, 1, 3], [3, 1, 1, 6], [3, 1, 3, 1], [3, 1, 3, 3],
  #    [3, 1, 3, 6], [3, 1, 6, 1], [3, 1, 6, 3], [3, 1, 6, 6],
  #    [3, 3, 1, 1], [3, 3, 1, 3], [3, 3, 1, 6], [3, 3, 3, 1],
  #    [3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 6], [3, 3, 6, 1], [3, 3, 6, 3],
  #    [3, 3, 6, 6], [3, 6, 1, 1], [3, 6, 1, 3], [3, 6, 1, 6],
  #    [3, 6, 3, 1], [3, 6, 3, 3], [3, 6, 3, 6], [3, 6, 6, 1],
  #    [3, 6, 6, 3], [3, 6, 6, 6], [6, 1, 1, 1], [6, 1, 1, 3],
  #    [6, 1, 1, 6], [6, 1, 3, 1], [6, 1, 3, 3], [6, 1, 3, 6],
  #    [6, 1, 6, 1], [6, 1, 6, 3], [6, 1, 6, 6], [6, 3, 1, 1],
  #    [6, 3, 1, 3], [6, 3, 1, 6], [6, 3, 3, 1], [6, 3, 3, 3],
  #    [6, 3, 3, 6], [6, 3, 6, 1], [6, 3, 6, 3], [6, 3, 6, 6],
  #    [6, 6, 1, 1], [6, 6, 1, 3], [6, 6, 1, 6], [6, 6, 3, 1],
  #    [6, 6, 3, 3], [6, 6, 3, 6], [6, 6, 6, 1], [6, 6, 6, 3],
  #    [6, 6, 6, 6]]
```

```
b.size
  #=> 81
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a sequence where each element is generated based on the previous one, there's [`Enumerator.produce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerator.html#produce-method), e.g.:

```
enum = Enumerator.produce([1, 1, 1, 1]) do |a, b, c, d|
  d += 1                # ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                        # initial value
  if d > 6
    d = 1
    c += 1
  end

  if c > 6
    c = 1
    b += 1
  end

  if b > 6
    b = 1
    a += 1
  end

  if a > 6
    raise StopIteration # <- stops enumeration
  end

  [a, b, c, d]          # <- return value = next value
end
```

I've kept the example intentionally simple, using an explicit variable for each of the four digits. You could of course also have an array and use a little loop to handle the increment / carry.

The above gives you:

```
enum.count        #=> 1296
enum.first(3)     #=> [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 3]]
enum.to_a.last(3) #=> [[6, 6, 6, 4], [6, 6, 6, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6]]
```